# Laravel : Force download from model instead of controller

Tags: php, laravel

I am using PHPExcel to generate an excel sheet and then output the file for download (force download). If I am to use the following from the controller file it works as expected:

```
return Response::download($file_path, 'myfile.xlsx');
```

But, I have to trigger this behavior from the Model and this does not seem to work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you have to trigger it from the model?

Comment: What do you mean with "trigger from the model"? The controller is supposed to return the response.

Comment: why not just have the model return the path, and return a response where it should, i.e. in the controller?

Comment: @castis and lukasgeiter, The requirement is to develop a class that would allow for report generation. If the controller that initiates this model wants to download the file, the relevant param has to be passed. The controller is the correct for dispatching these events but I'm afraid this is the requirement from the client.

Comment: @Damien, yes your absolutely right, this is the correct methodology but the requirement is to trigger the download via a specific model method so I have to opt for that

Comment: Its your job as the developer to advise on proper technique.

Comment: That's true castis, but the ball doesn't always swing your way :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the response's `send` method:

```
Response::download($file_path, 'myfile.xlsx')->send();
```

But I would suggest against this. It is not your model's job to handle HTTP responses.